# How to Search using wild card entries in Java Selenium

Tags: java, facebook, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have gone through every related question but none of them seems to provide the correct solution. I am writing a program to fetch the friend list from Facebook using selenium code. To do so, I am using `for` loop to scroll page down and fetch friends name link text from it using `tagname` keyword. While doing so, I get mutual friends and number of friends each friend have, also in the result.

I noticed that each friend id starts with `js_X` where X can be any value.
I need to know  how I can use any wild card search/Regular expression to search and fetch the results to me.

Below is my code(I know its poor programming, but please help me):

--code for opening facebook and reaching till Friendlist page here---

```
WebElement box = d.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='pagelet_timeline_app_collection_100000641984658:2356318349:2']/ul")); **//This find the first box containing friend list**
List<WebElement> FinalList = box.findElements(By.tagName("a")); **//All Names are fetched and added in Final List** 
jse.executeScript("scroll(0, 2500)"); **//Scrolled below to second box**
Thread.sleep(15000L);
box = d.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='pagelet_timeline_app_collection_100000641984658:2356318349:2']/ul[2]"));**//This finds second box and fetches all the friends name from that box**  
List<WebElement> IntermediateList; **//Temporarylist created**

for(int i=3,k=7; i<17||k<20; i++){  
    if(i<17){   
    box = d.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='pagelet_timeline_app_collection_100000641984658:2356318349:2']/ul["+i+"]"));
    if(box.isDisplayed()){  
        IntermediateList = box.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        FinalList.addAll(IntermediateList);
        jse.executeScript("scroll(0, "+k+"000)"); **//This is for increasing scroll everytime as sometimes box is further down**
        Thread.sleep(15000L);
        k++;    
     }else{     
         break;
     }
}

FinalList.addAll(IntermediateList);
```

Instead of `tagname("a")` I want to use `"id"` to find the friend name link text and use Regular expression/wild card in it to search.

For example : `IntermediateList = box.findElements(By.id("js_(wild card parameter)"));`

any Suggestion would help, Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You already used `xpath` in your example so why don't you use `xpath` to find the desired links?

**XPATH:**

```
IntermediateList = box.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'js_')]"));
```

(Find any element which `ID` contains `js_`)

**CSS:**

```
IntermediateList = box.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[id^='js_']"));
```

(Find a link `<a href...>` which ID *starts* with `js_`)

Comment: Above solution with xpath selects only six values from box containing more than 15 values. And with css Selector it does not select any value at all. What could be the reason? Any other solution?